# Limit ModelForm choices to options from a specific model

Tags: django, django-models

I tried this approached to allow project_id to be dynamic, but i get an error:"**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_id'".

```
forms.py

class CreateCostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,project_id,*args, **kwargs):

        super(CreateCostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cost_name'].queryset = ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id=project_id)

    class meta:
        model = ProjectCost
```

When i hard-code the value of project_id like:

```
self.fields['project_name'].queryset = ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id=4) or 
ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id= 8),
```

i get the correct filtered options on the form.So how can i make **project_id** dynamic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try getting the `project_id` from the `kwargs`, something like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id', None)
    super(CreateCostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['cost_name'].queryset = ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id=project_id)
```

Comment: Thanks,I tried that but the returned value of project_ id is 'None' and so no options are available on that field. When hardcode the value of project_id to test, like self.fields['cost_name'].queryset = ProjectCost.objects.filter(project_name_id= 4), the correct options are available. The value of project_id needs to update dynamically.